# Isolate ng-model in child directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for the best solution to create a form, built from the small functional blocks.

What I actually do:

Main controller loads the object and passes it to directive:

```
$scope.context= {model object};
<form><employee-context ng-model="context"></form>
```

`employeeContext` directive has it owns template built with another directives (That's what I call small functional blocks):

```
<base-section ng-model="baseModel"></base-section>
<address-section ng-model="addressModel"></address-section>
<details-section ng-model="detailsModel"></details-section>
```

`employeeContext` link function:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
  ngModel.$render = function() {
    scope.model = ngModel.$modelValue; //this is main model
    if (scope.model) {
      scope.baseModel = {
        name: scope.model.name,
        photoKey: scope.model.photoKey
      };
      scope.addressModel = scope.model.addresses;
      scope.detailsModel = scope.model.details;
    }
  };

  scope.$watch('addressModel', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal){
      scope.model.addresses = newVal;
      ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.model);
    }

  });

  scope.$watch('detailsModel', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal){
      scope.model.details = newVal;
      ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.model);
    }
  });
}
```

Above code is my solution to simplify building new context directives. Each time developer want to create new context, he must create similar directive, split the model and set his own html template. But this solution has some problems that I don't know how to resolve.

**The problem:**

I've expected that `ng-model` in each directive will be isolated from each other. But it is not. 
It means that each change inside lower level directives are automatically propagated to main model. I'd like to avoid this behaviour and update main model only with calling `ngModel.$setViewValue(updatedModel)` (for example only after button click).

Example functional block code:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
  ngModel.$render = function() {
    scope.adr = ngModel.$modelValue;
  };

  scope.updateModel = function(){
    _.each(scope.adr,function(m){
      m.city = m.city.toUpperCase();
    });
    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.adr);
  };
}
```

I'm also confused why this watches in context link function are fired only once - at initialization. They don't react with later model changes.

**My question is:**
What is the best solution to create some isolated scopes with a model passed  as `ngModel` and with the possibility to update this model only on demand.

[image]

Here is the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/vBUCwQHOT6GDDfJLNN5N?p=preview

Comment: Use `scope: {}` inside the directive to create individual child scopes?

Comment: @LloydBanks Did you see the plunkr? ;) Scopes are isolated but `ng-model` is not